# QT using QCustomPlot - Need to detect mouse not over chart

Tags: qt, qcustomplot

I am using QCustomPlot in a application which is focused on the graph which displays results from a external device. I have a cursor which uses  the QMouseEvent. Whenever I get the mouse event it draws a horizontal line and vertical line from the mouse position to the axis.

```
void PlotClass::ChartMouseMove(QMouseEvent* mouse){
    double x = ui->customplot->xAxis->pixelToCoord(mouse->pos().x());
    double y = ui->customplot->yAxis->pixelToCoord(mouse->pos().y());
    //QCPItemStraightLine *infLine = new QCPItemStraightLine(ui->customplot);
//    infLine->point1->setCoords(x, 0);  // location of point 1 in plot coordinate
//    infLine->point2->setCoords(2, 1);  // location of point 2 in plot coordinate
    qDebug() << x << y;
  //  ui->customplot->xAxis->range().minRange();
    double xLow = ui->customplot->xAxis->range().lower;
    double xHigh = ui->customplot->xAxis->range().upper;
    double yLow = ui->customplot->yAxis->range().lower;
    double yHigh = ui->customplot->yAxis->range().upper;

    infLinex->start->setCoords(x, yLow);  // location of point 1 in plot coordinate
    infLinex->end->setCoords(x, yHigh);  // location of point 2 in plot coordinate
    infLiney->start->setCoords(xLow, y);  // location of point 1 in plot coordinate
    infLiney->end->setCoords(xHigh, y);  // location of point 2 in plot coordinate
    ui->customplot->replot();
}
```

What I need to do is remove the cursor when the mouse is no longer over the chart. Not sure how to do this.

Also would be nice to paint the actual cursor position onto the lines in text (the values from the axis.)

Comment: Managed to get the cursor position on the screen but no idea how to get an event to make the cursor dissappear.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out. I just put this function call in the timer event (possibly not the best way but it works)

```
void PlotClass::CheckHidecursor(void){
    if(!Hidecursor && !ui->customplot->underMouse()){
        Hidecursor = true;
        infLinex->setVisible(false);
        infLiney->setVisible(false);
        yLabel->setVisible(false);
        xLabel->setVisible(false);
        qDebug() <<  "Hide";
        ui->customplot->replot();
    }

}
```

So it hides the lines and the numbers I am putting on if the mouse is no longer over the chart widget. The key function I found was QWidget::underMouse() which gives a true/false reponse.